# When changing the rotation of 3 phase motor, does it affect the cooling of the motor?

Tags: power

I had to change the direction of 3 phase motor rotation, it's working great, but does it affect badly any thing, like the cooling of the coils?

Comment: Depends on the motor design.  But usually - no problem reversing the direction of a 3-phase motor.  The datasheet will tell you for sure.

Comment: No. Because the motor for CW and CCW is the same. There are no  options when you buy it.

Comment: What type of 3 phase motor are you considering - Induction motor, synchronous AC, or Brushless DC (sensored or sensorless)? Is there a particular motor that you want to reverse?

Answer (score 2):

Some three-phase induction motors have an external cooling fan mounted on the motor shaft opposite the drive end. In my experience, that fan always has straight blades that move the air by centrifugal force and is equally effective when operating in either direction. Induction motors usually have fins on the ends of the rotor that are straight and move cooling air through the rotor by centrifugal action and are un-effected by direction of rotation.

If you have any type of three-phase motor of a design that would prevent proper operation in either direction, that fact would likely be clearly indicated on the motor.